# Finding specific values for all variables in a table using SAS EG

Tags: sas, macros

I have a table which contains one key id and 100 variables (x1, x2, x3 ..... x100) and i need to check every variables if there are any values stored as -9999, -8888, -7777, -6666 in of them.

For one variable i use

```
proc sql;
select keyid, x1 
from mytable 
where x1 in(-9999,-8888,-7777,-6666);
quit;
```

This is the data i am trying to get but it is just for one variable.

I do not have time for copying and pasting all the variables (100 times) in this basic query.
I have searched the forum but the answers i have found are a bit far from what i actually need
and since i am new to SAS i can not write a macro.

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just made up some sample data that resembles what you describe :-)

```
data have;
   do key = 1 to 1e5;
      array x x1 - x100;
      do over x;
         x = rand('integer', -10000, -5000);
      end;
      output;
   end;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   array x x1 - x100;
   do over x;
      if x in (-9999, -8888, -7777, -6666) then do;
         output;
         leave;
      end;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This code gives me all the variables for a uniqe key. What i really at the end is; 100 tables for each variable which contains only the given values and its unique id. With your code i get all the variables for every uniqe key.(Because with the code query finds a value for one of the variables and brings all the table)

Comment: If you want different output than your original question states then update the question.  But be specific about what you need and why.  It is normally going to make future processing harder rather than easier to split data into hundreds of datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SQL.  Instead use normal SAS code so you can take advantage of SAS syntax like ARRAYs and variable lists.

So make an array containing the variable you want to look at.  Then loop over the array.  There is no need to keep looking once you find one.

```
data want;
  set mytable;
  array list var1 varb another_var x1-x10 Z: ;
  found=0;
  do index=1 to dim(list) until (found);
     found = ( list[index] in (-9999 -8888 -7777 -6666) );
  end;
  if found;
run;
```

And if you want to search all of the numeric variables you can even use the special variable list _NUMERIC_ when defining the array:

```
array list _numeric_;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry i could not understrand this part. "array list var1 varb another_var x1-x10 Z: ;" i have 100 variables and they are like x1 x2 x3. Should i go like "array list var1 var2 var x1-x100 Z:;" ?

Comment: Look up the definition of the array statement.  Just list the names of the variables you want to search.  You did not tell us what your variable names where so I just made up some example names so you could see how the statement works.

Comment: i have looked several times. My variable names are x1, x2 till x100. Thanks for the help anyways. Dont have my work computer with me right now. I will try again monday.

Comment: If the names are that simple then just use `array list x1-x100;`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help i have found a solution and wanted to share it with you.
It has some points that needs to be evaluated but it is fine for me now. (gets the job done)

```
`%LET LIB = 'LIBRARY';
 %LET MEM = 'GIVENTABLE';
 %PUT &LIB &MEM;
 PROC SQL;
 SELECT 
 NAME INTO :VARLIST SEPARATED BY ' '
 FROM DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
 WHERE 
 LIBNAME=&LIB
 AND 
 MEMNAME=&MEM
 AND
 TYPE='num';
 QUIT;
 %PUT &VARLIST;
 %MACRO COUNTS(INPUT);
 %LOCAL i NEXT_VAR;
 %DO i=1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&VARLIST));
 %LET NEXT_VAR = %SCAN(&VARLIST, &i);
 PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE &NEXT_VAR AS
 SELECT
 COUNT(ID) AS NUMBEROFDESIREDVALUES
 FROM &INPUT
 WHERE
 &NEXT_VAR IN (6666, 7777, 8888, 9999)          
 GROUP BY
 &NEXT_VAR;
 QUIT;
 %END;
 %MEND;
 %COUNTS(GIVENTABLE);`
```

Comment: Please explain how the code works so others can learn from it.

Comment: First you give your references of your library and the table that contains the variables that you are willing to check the values. It creates a little macro so you do not have to write every other variable names. Instead with a small counting code it first goes to variable one then two then three and so on to the very last variable in given table. Then it looks for desired values in each value. At the end you can check how many of this values are found in each variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you provided to your own question gives more insight to what you really wanted. However, the solution you offered while it works is not very efficient. The SQL statement runs 100 times for each variable in the source data. That means the source table is read 100 times. Another problem is that it creates 100 output tables. Why?

A better solution is to create 1 table that contains the counts for each of the 100 variables. Even better is to do it in 1 pass of the source data instead of 100.

```
data sum;
set have end=eof;
array x(*) x:;
array csum(100) _temporary_;

do i = 1 to dim(x);
    x(i) = (x(i) in (-9999, -8888, -7777, -6666));  * flag (0 or 1) those meeting criteria;
    csum(i) + x(i);  * cumulative count;
    if eof then do;
        x(i) = csum(i); * move the final total to the orig variable;
    end;
end;

if eof then output;  * only output the final obs which has the totals;
drop key i;
run;
```

Partial result:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  ...
90  84  88  85  81  83  59  71  ...
```

You can keep it in that form or you can transpose it.

```
proc transpose data=sum out=want (rename=(col1=counts)) 
    name=variable;
run;
```

Partial result:

```
variable    counts
x1          90
x2          84
x3          88
x4          85
x5          81
...         ...
```